# what does <built-in>, <command-line> mean in a c-preprocessor output file

Tags: c-preprocessor

I came across the following in a Makefile:

```
CPP    =cpp
GFLAGS =-traditional-cpp -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP   \
-DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32

op1: ./Make/options
@$(CPP) $(GFLAGS) ./Make/options | sed -e 's@   *@ @g' > op1
```

The content in the ./Make/options is as follows:

```
EXE_INC = -I$/project/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude
EXE_LIBS = -lfiniteVolume
```

I checked to op1 file generated and the content is as follows:

```
# 1 "options"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 8 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4

# 17 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 3 4
```

I finally come to know this is related with c-preprocessor. I have no idea what those ,  mean. Can anyone explain what it tries to do by doing this?

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html for the GNU make manual. If you have a more specific question, ask it.

Comment: I searched through the manual. I didn't find content related with my question. @melpomene

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question why it's using cpp -traditional-cpp -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 rather than using g++ -traditional-cpp -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32. I didn't quite understand the meaning of cpp.

Comment: What does that have to do with `make`? Did you try reading the manual for `cpp` (`man cpp`)?

Comment: you are right. It has something to do with c-preprocessor, but nothing to do with make. Thank you. @melpomene

Answer (score 0):

`cpp` is the C preprocessor. This particular makefile appears to be using `cpp` (and `sed`) to generate the file `op1` from the `./Make/options` file.